# What does bytes.decode() with errors='replace' do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, decode

In the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

It says that `errors='replace'` is a valid option.... But what does it replace the invalid values WITH?

Comment: Did you read the "see section [Error Handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers)" part?

Comment: "possible values are 'ignore', 'replace' and any other name registered via codecs.register_error(), **see section Error Handlers**"

Answer (score 1):

Follow the documentation to [Error Handlers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) and it will explain that "replace" is applicable to text encodings.

> Value: `'replace'`
>   Meaning: Replace with a suitable replacement marker; Python will use the official `U+FFFD` REPLACEMENT CHARACTER for
>   the built-in codecs on decoding, and ‘?’ on encodingMeaning: Replace with a suitable replacement

[U+FFFD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) acts as a filler for bytes that cannot be decoded. It looks like this:

```
b'ab\xffcd'.decode('utf-8', 'replace')
# 'ab�cd'
```

Without the "replace" argument, you may get a `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
b'ab\xffcd'.decode('utf-8')
# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 2: invalid start byte
```